# Using BeautifulSoup's replaceWith to replace all 'a' tags with tag content

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

EDIT: Basically, I'm trying to perform a Decompose, but instead of removing a tag and completely destroying its contents, I'd like to replace the tag with its contents.

I'd like to replace all 'a' tags in an html document with the tag content in string format.  This would allow me to more easily write html to csv.  I can't get past the replace step however.  I've been trying to use BeautifulSoup's replace_with() to get it done, but the results are not coming back as expected.

```
# Import modules
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

# URL to soup
URL = 'http://www.barringtonhills-il.gov/foia/ordinances_12.htm'
html_content = urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)

# Replaces links with link text
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    linkText = link.contents[0]
    linkTextCln = '%s' % (linkText.string)
    if linkTextCln != 'None':
        link.replaceWith(linkTextCln)
        print link
```

This returns:

```
<a href="index.htm">Home</a>
<a href="instruct.htm">Instructions</a>
<a href="requests.htm">FOIA Requests</a>
<a href="kiosk.htm">FOIA Kiosk</a>
<a href="geninfo.htm">Government Profile</a>
etc etc etc
```

But the expected return is:

```
Home
Instructions
FOIA Requests
FOIA Kiosk
Government Profile
etc etc etc
```

Any thoughts on why replaceWith isn't working as expected?  Is there a better approach to this question altogether?

Comment: You still end up with non-string HTML contents in your results. Returns: 
    [<img src="images/vbh.jpg"/>]
    [u'Home']
    [u'Instructions']
    [u'FOIA Requests']
    etc... etc...

Comment: The link.contents vs linkTextCln isn't my issue however -- attempting to replace the link tags with link.contents doesn't work either.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to perform a Decompose, but instead of removing a tag and completely destroying its contents, I'd like to replace the tag with its contents/

Answer (score 0):

I believe with bs4, the method is now `replace_with` but if you're just looking to output the contents of the tags, the following works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''
<a href="index.htm">Home</a>
<a href="instruct.htm">Instructions</a>
<a href="requests.htm">FOIA Requests</a>
<a href="kiosk.htm">FOIA Kiosk</a>
<a href="geninfo.htm">Government Profile</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(tag.string)
```

Output:

```
Home
Instructions
FOIA Requests
FOIA Kiosk
Government Profile
[Finished in 0.2s]
```